# Trouble with Creating Test DB in UnitTest

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am creating a unit test for some functions that I have created that interact with a database.  I have some setup and tear down code for a database that I planed on using in theses unit tests.  Now the funny part is that this code performs correctly when in WinForms, Console, DLL Library, however when the code is executed in a Unit test I get an interesting exception when it tries to run the ExecuteNonQuery() command.

```
[Outer Exception]
Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation
[Inner Exception]
The C++ module failed to load during appdomain initialization. \n
```

Upon further digging in my exception I found the following inner, inner exception:

```
Unable to load DLL 'MSVCR80.dll": The specfiied module could not be found ...  The C++ module fialed to load during appdomain initialization.
```

When looking at the stack trace you find this:

```
"at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecuteBatch.GetStatements(String sqlCommand)
```

Now I am going to admit I am a little in over my head here so if anyone can explain why this exception is being thrown when executed as part of a UnitTest and a means to fix it that would be GREAT!

```
private static void ExecSql(string sql, string connectionString)
{
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    try
    {
      conn.Open();
      Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
      server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
      server.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
      //MessageBox.Show("Script Executed.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try locating the mentioned DLL in your system, and put its copy into `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32` folder. If necessary, run `regsvr32.exe MSVCRO80.dll` from that folder.

Comment: I have located the "missing" DLL and placed it in the %SYSTEMROOT%\system32 as you had suggested and it still gives me the same issue....